# VS 2017 unable to attach to w3wp

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug a .NET site (local IIS) hosting the DLL I'm developing using VS 2017 Community Edition (on a Windows 7 Enterprise workstation).

When I try to attach to w3wp.exe linked to the application pool, I get an error saying :
Unable to attach to the process. An unknown error occurred in the Windows Web Service infrastructure (translation from french message).

The connection type is set to Default
The connection target is the local computer
I can see the w3wp.exe process in the list provided by VS and it is of type x64 (no mention of managed code).

Is there an option I'm missing to be able to debug a 64 bits .NET app ?

Any tips welcome

Thanks in advance

Comment: you probably want to restart VS once

Comment: I also experienced that VS is required to be run as an administrator even if I run the IIS app-pool with my identity for some reason.

Comment: VS is running as an administrator, restarted many times but no more chance, still unable to debug :'(

Comment: Have you tried resetting IIS?

Comment: Yep, resetting IIS, even changing .NET Framework version (4.6.1) have been done but nothing changes

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: @Dominique, Please change your project target. Go to Properties of your project->Build-Platform Target and set value to x86/Any CPU/X64, view the result.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I've tried to change the target but I cannot use 32 bits due to some DLL out of my scope that must use 64 bits. Using x64 or Any CPU provide the same error.

Comment: @hellyale I've tried to reinstall VS which implies a computer restart at the end of the process, but it didn't change anything. Still impossible to debug my DLL.

Comment: hhmmmm in this thread : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bd1076f4-8eb7-4ffc-b08c-5adb99490eb3/unrecognized-error-occoured-in-the-windows-web-services-framework?forum=vsdebug it seems antivirus and firewall were the culprit?

Comment: @hellyale As I'm on a profesional computer, I cannot disable the antivirus nor the firewall. I've just changed my computer but with my previous one the debugging was possible even if I was in the same configuration.

Comment: @Dominique, If you just create a new simple project, could you attach to that process in your side? If all projects have the same issue, I agree with hellyale's suggestion, maybe we would think about the windows Environment like firewall, Anti-virus software or others. Another suggestion is that just add a new admin user in your windows, and then log-in with the new user, debug your app again. At least, we could know that whether it was related to the previous account. Please also reset VS settings, view the result.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I've tried to debug notepad (64 bits version) :  it failed. Regarding the configuration of the mobile PC, I've discovered that a VPN client was installed and configured so that when I connect to a private network it allows me to connect to my business. This client was not present on my previous computer which was a desktop computer. So I guess that this client interferes with debuging. I will try to investigate on that with my Network admin. Thanks for all your responses. Regards

Comment: @Dominique, What about this issue? Could you attach to that process now?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I've changed the DLL that was prohibiting the 32 bits support on my ApplicationPool. By that way I was able to debug my code and to attach to the process but have no ideas why I had to do so. I didn't get any response from my Network admin at the moment, will make un update as soon as I had it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dominique, Thanks for your response, if you could debug it after you enable the 32 bit, I think it would be not the VS debugging tool issue, it would be related to the IIS configurations: https://forums.iis.net/t/1181555.aspx?Running+both+32+bit+and+64+bit+Applications+on+IIS7 and https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/138114/How-to-enable-the-bit-compatibility-on-IIS-and.